# How to compile CLOGS library

Tags: c++, boost, opencl

I want to compile [CLOGS](https://sourceforge.net/projects/clogs/) library.I follow [this](http://clogs.sourceforge.net/doc/clogs-user.html#installation) manual.
I use Visual Studio 2010,python 3.4 in windows 10 x64.
I didn't know anything about waf building system.I didn't know how to set Boost's include path. So I copy boost to the include path of msvc 10.

when I run `python waf configure --without-xsltproc --msvc_version="msvc 10.0"`

the result is [image]

It found foreach.hpp but not found program_options.hpp.But they were at same folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2013 (for x64 environment)

boost 1.61.0

clogs 1.5.0

1. Do install **boost prebuilt binary** for your VS version(Not source version)
   Prebuilt binary should have lib64-msvc-12.0 folder that has boost_program_options-vc120-mt-1_61.lib for program_options build testing.
2. Set two windows global environments

   - INCLUDE=C:\yourboostroot;C:\youropenclheaderpath
   - LIBPATH=C:\yourboostroot\lib64-msvc-12.0;C:\youropencllibpath
3. Open VS2013 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt
4. Go to your clogs source root and type

   - python waf configure --without-doxygen --without-xsltproc

in this case I do not need cl-headers configure options